# Apache with Wsgi Module changes in source file does not get affected immediately

Tags: python, django, apache

Apache with Wsgi Module changes in django app source file does not get affected immediately but it reflects the changes only when the apache restarts.

configuration of my apache setting is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName pyspacex.com
ServerAlias pyspacex.com
CustomLog logs/pyspacex-access_log common
ErrorLog logs/pyspacex-error_log

Alias /static/ /home/mrll0081/mysite/spacex/static/

<Directory /home/mrll0081/mysite/spacex/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess pyspacex python-home=/home/mrll0081/pyenv python-path=/home/mrll0081/mysite                                                                            
WSGIProcessGroup pyspacex
WSGIScriptAlias /spacex /home/mrll0081/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/mrll0081/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ok. And the question is??

Comment: I just updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please don't upload images but text your code so we can copy/paste. Try doing in your command line **touch /home/mrll0081/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py**